# Message not showing on route redirect

Tags: php, laravel

How come when I redirect I am not getting my success message  I am wanting it so that I can just change the alert "var":

**HTML:**

```
<div class="flash-message">
    @foreach(['warning', 'success'] as $flashMsg)
        @if(Session::has('alert-' . $flashMsg))
            <p class="alert alert-{{ $flashMsg }}">{{Session::get('alert-' . $flashMsg)}}</p>
            @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
   return redirect()->route("newUser")->with('alert-success', $fName . $lName . 'Was Successfully Added');
```

**Route:**

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'web'], function() {

    /* Admin Auth */
    Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
    Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
    Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
    Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

  Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth.admin'], function(){
    /*Admin Dashboard Routes */
        Route::get('dashboard', 'AdminController@getDashboard');
        Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@getDashboard');
        Route::get('general/settings', 'AdminController@generalSettings');

        Route::get('users', 'UserController@getDashboard');
        Route::get('users/new',['as' => 'newUser', 'uses' => 'UserController@addNewUser']);

        Route::post('users/new/add', 'UserController@addNewUserSubmit');

        Route::post('general/settings/gSubmit/{id}',['as' => 'generalDataSubmit',      'uses' => 'AdminController@generalSettingsGeneralSubmit']);
        Route::post('general/settings/sSubmit/{id}',['as' => 'socialDataSubmit',       'uses'  => 'AdminController@generalSettingsSocialSubmit']);
        Route::post('general/settings/vSubmit/{id}',['as' => 'verificationDataSubmit', 'uses' => 'AdminController@generalSettingsVerificationDataSubmit']);


    });
});
```

Comment: which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: Can you put your routes file on the topic?

Comment: Also check if your laravel has a RouteServiceProvider (I think it's generated by the make:auth). This file already put your routes file within the "web" middleware and you should not put it yourself. Check this note https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart#routing and this issue https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12022

Comment: @GabrielMoretti done

Comment: is this route group within another group?

Comment: @GabrielMoretti Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'web'], function() {

Comment: Try removing web middleware. If you have the RouteServiceProvier, probably it's already including your entire routes file within this middleware and putting it again will cause this strange behaviour.

Comment: @GabrielMoretti Have edited with full route - I cant see how that will work

Comment: Didn't work?
Does your RouteServiceProvider have something like this:protected function mapWebRoutes(Router $router)
    {
        $router->group([
            'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',
        ], function ($router) {
            require app_path('Http/routes.php');
        });
    }

Comment: @GabrielMoretti Yes but if I remove my routes.  My inner group is because I wanted a different redirect on login fail

Comment: You can leave it like this, just remove the web middleware from the parent group. If you RouteServiceProvider is like I said, you already have this middleware by default. Try this `Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin'], ....`

Comment: @GabrielMoretti still does not give me the success

Comment: Im sorry, I think I can't help you then. I'm out of ideas. I've had them same issue and it was solved by doing what I told above. Hope you can fix it. Please let me know if you do.